# How can I get such as `new()` constraint by reflection. ()

Tags: c#

e.g:

generic parameter `T` can contains many constraints:

```
public Class<T> where T : class, IDisponse, new()
{
}
```

how can I get all constraint of `T` by reflection?

I already known:

```
var t = typeof(Class<>).GetGenericArguments()[0]
t.IsValueType // should be struct?
t.GetGenericParameterConstraints() // should be IDisponse or other type?
```

**but how to get other constraints:**

- class
- new()

Comment: There is an example of code that does this on MSDN https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenericparameterconstraints(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @vcsjones that is helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Type.GenericParameterAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.genericparameterattributes(v=vs.110).aspx) property:

> Gets a combination of GenericParameterAttributes flags that describe
>   the covariance and special constraints of the current generic type
>   parameter.

I.e. it returns bitwise mask of generic parameter constraints. E.g. if you want to check if there is `new()` constraint:

```
var attributes = t.GenericParameterAttributes;
if ((attributes & GenericParameterAttributes.DefaultConstructorConstraint) != 0)
  //....
```

For `class` constraint validation you should check for `ReferenceTypeConstraint` flag.

Answer (score -3):

You are trying to create a new instance by reflection?

Use the System.Activator class.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator(v=vs.110).aspx

```
T instance = (T)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(T));
```

Comment: Do not ask counter questions in answers. Please use comments to confirm what OP requires.